# How to get the value from an input box

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code and I am not sure how to get the value from an input box.
This is my html code:

```
        <div id = "login">
            <p>User <input type = "text" id = "username"></p>
            <p>Password <input type = "password" id = "password"></p>
            <button onclick = "login(?,?)">Log In</button>  
        </div>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
function login(name, password){
    alert('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};
```

How do you get the value from an input box?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are n number of ways to get the value from input. Liek getting from id or by class or by many other ways. Before asking question , it doesn't hurt to do some research on our own. This is very basic and you can easily grasp the basics from w3schools.com or mozilla mdn for more detailed understanding. :)

Comment: There must be hundreds of Javascript tutorials that explain how to get input values. THis question demonstrates absolutely no attempt to learn on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id = "login">
            <p>User <input type = "text" id = "username"></p>
            <p>Password <input type = "password" id = "password"></p>
            <button onclick = "login(document.getElementById('username').value, document.getElementById('password').value)">Log In</button>  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
function login(){

    name = document.getElementById('username');
    password = document.getElementById('password');
    alert('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};
```

in HTML :

```
<button onclick = "login()">Log In</button>
```

Comment: This won't work because name and password variable value are initialized when the page loads and the name and password value will be blank, so you have to initialize these variables inside login function.

Comment: @sajalsuraj : yes your right. I changed the code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:**
thanks to @sajalsuraj

```
<div id = "login">
    <p>User <input type = "text" id = "username"></p>
    <p>Password <input type = "password" id = "password"></p>
    <button onclick = "login()">Log In</button>  
</div>


function login(){
    var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    alert('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};
```

Comment: on button click, it should be like <button onclick="login()"></button>

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @smoqadam answer,

```
function login(name, password){
   alert('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};

 name = document.getElementById('username').value;
 password = document.getElementById('password').value;
 login(name,password);
```

If using Jquery,

```
 function login(){
    $name = $('#username').val();
    $pass = $('#password').val();
    alert('UserName: '+$name+' Password: '+$pass);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend *not* to bind to events this way.
Here's a better example of the bare minimum you are trying to do. I would also suggest using native html `form` functionality. Consider reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

```js
// add event listener to loginButton with handler, that will get username and password from html
document.getElementById('loginButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  login(username, password);
  
});

// function to process login.
function login (username, password) {
  alert('username ' + username + '; password ' + password);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>User <input type="text" id="username" /></p>
    <p>Password <input type="password" id="password" /></p>
    <button id="loginButton">Log In</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div id="login">
  <p>User <input type="text" id="username"></p>
  <p>Password <input type="password" id="password"></p>
  <button onclick="getData()">Log In</button>  
</div>
```

**Javascript code :**

```
function getData() {
name = document.getElementById('username');
password = document.getElementById('password');
getLogin(name,password);
}    

function getLogin(name, password){
    Console.log('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be **to not include JS code inside html code**, instead just reference the login button from your js code and add an event to it.
So you get advantage of caching later on, here is an example:

```
<!-- HTML markup -->

<div id = "login">
    <p>User <input type = "text" id = "username"></p>
    <p>Password <input type = "password" id = "password"></p>
    <button>Log In</button>  
</div>


<!-- method1 using script tag -->

<script>
  var loginButton = document.querySelector('#login button');
  var username,password;

  loginButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
      username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      password = document.getElementById('password').value;

      alert('username: ' + username + '\n password : ' + password);
  });

</script>


<!-- 
     method2 include a login.js script(containing the previous js code)    
     to benefit from caching when refreshing or visiting 
     the page in the next time 
-->

<script src="login.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get value of html element like this 
**document.getElementById('username').value**

```js
function login(name, password){
  var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  alert('Your username is ' + name + ' and your password is ' + password);
};
```

```css
#login{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 50px;
}
label{
width:70px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <p><label>User</label> <input type="text" id="username"></p>
  <p><label>Password</label> <input type = "password" id = "password"></p>
  <button onclick="login();">Log In</button>  
        </div>
```